# How do I inform HAProxy that my server is back up?

Tags: haproxy, docker

I'm a bit of a HAProxy newbie - I've got 3 docker containers, one running HAProxy with the following config:

```
global                                                                             
  log 127.0.0.1 local0                                                             
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice                                                      
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy                                                          
  user haproxy                                                                     
  group haproxy                                                                    
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin                          
  # daemon                                                                         

defaults                                                                           
  log global                                                                       
  mode http                                                                        
  option httplog                                                                   
  option dontlognull                                                               
  timeout connect 5000ms                                                           
  timeout client 50000ms                                                           
  timeout server 50000ms                                                           
  balance source                                                                   

listen stats :80                                                                   
  stats enable                                                                     
  stats uri /haproxy?stats                                                         
  stats realm Strictly\ Private                                                    
  stats auth test:test1234                                                         
  balance roundrobin                                                               
  #option forwardfor                                                               
  default_backend myserv-legacy                                                    

backend myserv-legacy                                                              
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect preserve                                         
  server myserv-A ${MYSERVA_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR}:8080 cookie A check               
  server myserv-B ${MYSERVB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR}:8080 cookie B check
```

The other two servers are running a webapp using Tomcat.

I brought my two servers down with `sudo docker stop myservA myservB`, and though I've started them and can connect to them through their exposed ports, they both show as down in HAProxy with a `L4TOUT` in 2000ms.

Any clue why they wouldn't be showing up as available?

**edit**:

If I run

```
$ sudo docker stop haprox && sudo docker start haprox
```

(haprox is the name of my HAProxy container) then my servers are available again...

Comment: It looks like the issue here is that the IP changes. HAProxy is still looking at the old IP instead of the new one. If I could use hostnames instead of IP addresses then this would be straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just about to ask if the value of the address variables was changing, heh.

The way I've been seeing this done in dynamic containered environments is to use a service discovery tool like etcd or Consul to help the load balancer find the backends - looks like [Consul has a tool specifically for the HAProxy use case.](https://hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html)